# Import typescript file to an angular typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a type script file like this:

```js
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName: string, public middleInitial: string, public lastName: string) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

let user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
```

I want to add it into an angular component (exactly in it typescript file). 
How can I do that? (I have searched but I haven't found any answer I need)

Comment: You want to add all this in *one* typescript file? Also, what are you trying to achieve with this component?

Comment: I try to run the function in the typescript with the data in the class which has an implemented interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

create .ts file name `model.ts`

inside that

```
export interface  Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

in accessing page eg: `home.ts`

import file

```
import * as models_app from '../../models';
```

set value

```
 private selectedInstrument: models_app.Person = {
        firstName:"chanaka";
        lastName:"weerasinghe";
    }
```

Comment: So how can i implement the interface in another class?

Comment: you have to import that class thats it